# equation of the tangent to the following curves?

Tags: calculus

example:
$f(x)=x^2  (2,4)$
  $= x^2$ 
  at x= 2 
$f(x) 2^2=4$ 
$y=mx+c$ 
$y=4x+c$ 
$(2,4)$ 
$4=4\cdot2+c$ 
$4-8=c$ 
$c=-4$ 
$y=4x-4$ 
but below question 
I don't know how to solve? 
$F(x)=x^2-2x+5$   at $x= -1$
the answer is $y=-4x+4$
thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Differentiate $F$ and evaluate at $x=-1$ to get the slope, then use the point-slope form of the equation for a line.

Comment: can you please explain in a step? thx~ @J.M.

Comment: Answer these first: 1. What is the derivative of $x^2-2x+5$? 2. Do you recall how to construct the equation of a line with a given slope and passing through a given point?

Comment: 1. $2x-2$ but i don't know 2?

Comment: What you wrote is a bunch of formulas, some of which make no sense, though you arrived at the right tangent line. For instance, there is the $(2,4)=x^2$ in the first line, the $f(x)2^2=4$ on the third line, the bare $(2,4)$ on the sixth line. Connecting text is necessary.  We have $f(x)=x^2$.  Therefore $f'(x)=2x$.  So at $x=2$, the tangent line has slope $f'(2)$, which is $4$. And so on. For the next function, $f(x)=x^2-2x+5$, so $f'(x)=2x-2$. We have $f'(-1)=-4$, so our tangent line has slope $-4$. But $f(-1)=8$, so our tangent line passes through $(-1,8)$. Continue.

Comment: If the line $y=mx+c$ passes through the point $(a,b)$ then $b=ma+c$ so $c=b-ma$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Added*: concerning the first part of your question, you should edit it. As a minimum, something like the following.

Example: $f(x)=x^2$. At $x=2$, $f(x)=2^2=4$. The equation of the tangent at   $(2,4)$ is

$$y=mx+c,$$

where $m$ is $f'(2)=4$. And so,  $y=4x+c$, and $$4=4\cdot 2+c\Leftrightarrow 4-8=c\Leftrightarrow  c=-4.$$ Therefore, $y=4x-4$.

---

Using your notation, the equation of a straight line is

$$y=mx+c\tag{1},$$

where $m$ is its slope. If this line passes through the point $P(a,b)
$, then the coordinates $a,b$ must satisfy the equation

$b=ma+c\tag{2}.$

Subtracting $(2)$ from $(1)$, we get

$$y-b=m(x-a),\tag{3}$$

which is equivalent to

$$y=mx-ma+b.\tag{3'}$$

*The slope of the tangent line to the graph of the function $f(x)$ at the point $
(a,b)=(a,f(a))$ is equal to the derivative of the function at $x=a$, i.e. $m=f^{\prime }(a)$* (Wikipedia [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative#Differentiation_and_the_derivative)). Therefore, the equation of the
tangent is given by (see sketch)

$$y=f^{\prime }(a)x-f^{\prime }(a)a+f(a).\tag{4}$$

[image]

For the second function $F(x)=x^{2}-2x+5$, the equation of the tangent at $(-1,F(-1))=(-1,(-1)^{2}-2(-1)+5)=(-1,8)$ is

$$y=F^{\prime }(-1)x-F^{\prime }(-1)\left( -1\right) +8.$$

The derivative $F^{\prime }(x)=2x-2$ and $F^{\prime }(-1)=2\left( -1\right)
-2=-4$. Consequently, the equation of the tangent is

$$y=-4x-(-4)\left( -1\right) +8,$$

which is equivalent to

$$y=-4x+4.\tag{5}$$

Comment: fantastic answer! Thanks alot. Sorry for my bad question. Now I fully understood~ thx @AméricoTavares

Comment: sorry! how do you get $y=-4x-(-4)(-1)+8$ ?

Comment: @SbSangpi: Just substitute $F'(-1)=-4$ in the equation $y=F'(-1)x-F'(-1)(-1)+8$.